# Angular - Optimize HTTP calls for displaying components

Tags: angular, angular-components

How would you solve this ?

**Setup**: I have this page where I can navigate between components based on where the user clicks on the side menu

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSI1z.png)

**Problem**: Each component displayed needs to do an API get call to get a table on which users can do CRUD actions, so there is a loading time every time the user switches view.

**Question**: How can I optimize this to avoid the loading time on each component ? I thought about doing a single get call inside the parent component then passing each data to its corresponding component via an "@Input" but is the data going to be fresh enough knowing that inside each component there is a CRUD table the user can interact with ?

Thanks for reading me

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can either make the API calls to the parent component and pass them to the children, risking the data aren't up to date when the user views the corresponding component, or make the API calls when each component is loaded and have some loading time.

A mix of the two is also possible (but maybe more complex than needed):
You could do all the `GET` API calls on the parent component and redo them everytime a child component initializes, and only update the view if there is a difference in the data. If you wanna go that route look into state management (ngrx or something similar).